# Multiple Select Options Redirect

Tags: jquery, redirect, select

I am new to Jquery and stuck with something: I have three select dropdowns with multiple options, and I want them to redirect to multiple pages depending on the choices made. For example:

If select option 1 = A and select option 2 = B redirect = Page 1B

Similarly

If select option 1 = A and select option 2 = C redirect = Page 1C

Comment: Can you share the code of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery get the value of each select box using val()

For example

```
// If selectBox1 is set to A and selectBox2 is set to B, then redirectLocation will be AB
var redirectLocation = $("#selectBox1").val() + $("#selectBox2").val();

// Redirect to the URL with the selected values
window.location.href = "http://yourdomainIguess.com/" + redirectLocation;
```

An important thing to note is that your selectboxes value is different from the text content. You can define a value that's different from the selectbox display using the value attribute in HTML.

For example

```
<select id="selectBox1">
  <option value="A">Alpha</option>
  <option value="B">Beta</option>
  <option value="C">Charlie</option>
</select>
```

On these if you use `$("#selectBox1").val()` you'll get A, B  or C. If you want the text content instead, use `$("#selectBox1").text()` and it will give you Alpha, Beta, or Charlie

If you want to use the selected index instead of the text or value then you can use jQuerys prop function to get a selectboxes selected index

```
// Will give us 1B if we select A and B
var redirectLocation = ($("#selectBox1").prop('selectedIndex')+1) + $("#selectBox2").val();

// Redirect to the URL with the selected values
window.location.href = "http://yourdomainIguess.com/" + redirectLocation;
```

Keep in mind that Index will be 0 based. So the first option will return 0 and the second will return 1. I've added one to the index in the code to make it give a 1 for the first element instead.

You can also check these values to redirect to different pages

```
// Store our values
var selectVal1 = $("#selectBox1").val();
var selectVal2 = $("#selectBox2").val();

if(selectVal1 == 'A' && selectVal2 == 'B'){
    // If the selected values are A and B then go to google
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
}
else {
    // Otherwise go to Yahoo
    window.location.href = "https://www.yahoo.com/";
}
```

If you want to run the redirect on the select box change you can just bind the event like this

```
// Use the ID of the select box to bind an event
$("#selectBox1").change(function() {
    // Do things in here

    var selectVal1 = $("#selectBox1").val();
    var selectVal2 = $("#selectBox2").val();

    if(selectVal1 == 'A' && selectVal2 == 'B'){
        window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
    }
    else {
       window.location.href = "https://www.yahoo.com/";
    }
});
```

Comment: This is huge, molding it according to my needs and will post results here, wondering if I can add a button as well...

Comment: I saw your example below, the reason why you're having issues is because you're binding your events within the if statement. You need to place the code for getting the values and the if statement within the click event function.

Comment: .click() binds a function to an event. So the button will only work after you call it. Because your event binds are in an if statement that is in $(document).ready it'll only call .click() if the select boxes have a selected value when the page is loaded. The reason why the button works after refresh is likely because you're using a browser that retains select box values, I know Firefox does.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help David. This worked:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
 var selectVal1 = $("#selectBox1").val();
 var selectVal2 = $("#selectBox2").val();
 $("#selectBox1").change(function() {
            selectVal1 = $("#selectBox1 option:selected").val();
    });
 $("#selectBox2").change(function() {
            selectVal2 = $("#selectBox2 option:selected").val();
    });
 
 $("#click").click(function() {
 
 if(selectVal1 == 'A' && selectVal2 == 'A'){
  
  location = "https://www.google.com/";    
}
 else if(selectVal1 == 'A' && selectVal2 == 'B'){
  
  location = "https://www.yahoo.com/";
    
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectBox1">
  <option value="">Where are you located?</option>
  <option value="A">Option A</option>
  <option value="B">Option B</option>
</select>
<select id="selectBox2">
  <option value="">What is your Need?</option>
  <option value="A">Option A</option>
  <option value="B">Option B</option>
</select>
<input id="click" type="button" value="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your answer, I have made an example... tried it locally, it only works if I refresh the page and hit submit... Weird!

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var selectVal1 = $("#selectBox1").val();
 var selectVal2 = $("#selectBox2").val();
 
 if(selectVal1 == 'A' && selectVal2 == 'A'){
  $("#click").click(function() {
  window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
    });
}
 else if(selectVal1 == 'A' && selectVal2 == 'B'){      
  $("#click").click(function() {
  window.location.href = "https://yahoo.com/";
    });
}
 else if(selectVal1 == 'A' && selectVal2 == 'C'){      
  $("#click").click(function() {
  window.location.href = "https://bing.com/";
    });
}
 else if(selectVal1 == 'A' && selectVal2 == 'D'){      
  $("#click").click(function() {
  window.location.href = "https://duckduckgo.com";
    });
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectBox1">
  <option value="">Where are you located?</option>
  <option value="A">Option A</option>
  <option value="B">Option B</option>
  <option value="C">Option C</option>
  <option value="D">Option D</option>
</select>
<select id="selectBox2">
  <option value="">What is your Need?</option>
  <option value="A">Option A</option>
  <option value="B">Option B</option>
  <option value="C">Option C</option>
  <option value="D">Option D</option>
</select>
<input id="click" type="button" value="submit">
```